# Render language specific content from resource bundle

Tags: jsp, character-encoding, resourcebundle

I've a requirement to display the locale specific information from a resource bundle. I've locale specific text characters in those bundles. I pasted the language specific content and used Notepad to save it. While saving the content, I choose `UTF-8` as the encoding type.

Now in my JSP page, I need to load the bundle. I use `<fmt:setBundle/>` to load the bundle. *It is loading the correct bundle based on the locale*. This is working fine. But the problem is with rendering the content. It is not able to render the content properly. 
I set the encoding at the page level.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

I also tried setting the setting the encoding using `<fmt:requestEncoding/>` to set the encoding. None of these worked.
Can you please help me to fix this?

Comment: What does 'not able to render the content properly.' mean in detail. Any examples, screen shots?

Comment: It comes lik @#$#@$%@@%%%....something like this.

Comment: What happens if you open the file in _Edit Plus_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that your bundle is a PropertyResourceBundle, i.e. it's backed by a properties file. Properties file should be encoded in ISO 8859-1. The native2ascii tool coming with the JDK must be used to translate a file using some other encoding in ISO 8859-1 (non translatable chars will be unicode-escaped). This is all described in the [Properties javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), as well as the [PropertyResourceBundle javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html).

Comment: OK. i was able to convert to unicode using native2ascii tool. Now I'm able to see the correct text when I use java.util.ResourceBundle to load the property file. But when I use <fmt:message/> tag to load it it is giving ???key?????

Comment: Either you're using an inexistent key, or an inexistent bunde, or not the bundle you think. Without seeing code, it's hard to tell. Ask another question if you don't find the problem.